# Tallying a list from the other

Tags: excel, list, countif

So we have two sets of data

List of towns where we were supposed to reach (Target cities) --> a list of distinct 7428 towns

List of towns where we have actually reached (Acquired cities) --->a list of 19878 towns with a lot of them being repeated but distinct count 3777 towns.

Now my task is to check which of the target cities have we actually gone and acquired.

Spellings on both the sheet ( Target and acquired) might not be same for a city due to human error.

What do i do. Please help.

Comment: Use index with match to indicate if a city is in both lists, then sort by the results.

Comment: ^^^^ but that will expect exact spelling matches.  You will need a fuzzy lookup to do the misspelling matches.  Microsoft has its own addon for that.  A quick google search of fuzzy lookup will link you to it.